# Grep for Tron - A 5 second problem

Tags: grep

I have a problem with a simple solution. i need to grep Tron*.exe out of

```
<li><a href="Tron%20v9.6.1%20(2016-10-03).exe"> Tron v9.6.1 (2016-10-03).exe</a></li>
<li><a href="Tron%20v9.6.1%20(2016-10-03).torrent"> Tron v9.6.1 (2016-10-03).torrent</a></li>
<li><a href="md5sums.txt"> md5sums.txt</a></li>
<li><a href="md5sums.txt.asc"> md5sums.txt.asc</a></li>
<li><a href="sha256sums.txt"> sha256sums.txt</a></li>
<li><a href="sha256sums.txt.asc"> sha256sums.txt.asc</a></li>
```

I need this to work for the list even if the text changes version number or date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`grep` with PCRE (`-P`), extracting only the matched portion (`-o`):

```
grep -Po '"\KTron[^"]*\.exe' file
```

In the Regex pattern:

- `"` matches a literal `"`, `\K` discards the match
- `Tron` matches literal `Tron`
- `[^"]*` matches zero or more characters that are not `"`
- `\.exe` matches literal `.exe`

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
<li><a href="Tron%20v9.6.1%20(2016-10-03).exe"> Tron v9.6.1 (2016-10-03).exe</a></li>
<li><a href="Tron%20v9.6.1%20(2016-10-03).torrent"> Tron v9.6.1 (2016-10-03).torrent</a></li>
<li><a href="md5sums.txt"> md5sums.txt</a></li>
<li><a href="md5sums.txt.asc"> md5sums.txt.asc</a></li>
<li><a href="sha256sums.txt"> sha256sums.txt</a></li>
<li><a href="sha256sums.txt.asc"> sha256sums.txt.asc</a></li>

$ grep -Po '"\KTron[^"]*\.exe' file.txt
Tron%20v9.6.1%20(2016-10-03).exe
```